# lag dependent variable among explanatory variables on panel data analysis

Tags: panel-data

Can I manually include lag dependent variable among explanatory variables on panel data model estimations( in trying to establish relationship between gross profit/earning before interest and tax as dependent variable for equations 1&2 repectively. Raw material, work in progress, finish good inventories are the independent variables.logFsize, Year Dummy - control variables.

Comment: What's "lag dependent variable"?

Comment: one year lagged dependent variable

Comment: i mean one year lagged dependent variable(gross profit/earnings b/4 interest and tax)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?